# acinclude.m4: file '$1/module.ac' does not exist

Tags: autoconf, m4

I'm trying to port http://fossies.org/linux/privat/old/fget-1.3.3.tar.gz/

moved `autoconf/aclocal.m4` to `acinclude.m4`, because this file was not included by autoreconf and I also changed:

```
-m4_include([encap.m4])
-m4_include([ac_path_generic.m4])
+m4_include([autoconf/encap.m4])
+m4_include([autoconf/ac_path_generic.m4])
```

This file also contains:

```
AC_DEFUN([PSG_MODULE], [
  m4_define([subdir], [$1])dnl
  m4_include([$1/module.ac])dnl
  m4_ifdef([$1][_INIT], [$1][_INIT($@)])dnl
  m4_undefine([subdir])dnl
])
```

The line `PSG_MODULE([compat])` now fails:

```
$ autoreconf -fi
aclocal: error: acinclude.m4:194: file '$1/module.ac' does not exist
autoreconf: aclocal failed with exit status: 1
```

Comment: have you tried removing the line `m4_include([$1/module.ac])dnl` to see what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced `$1` with the macro `subdir` that was already there:

```
m4_include(subdir[/module.ac])dnl
```